# AutoMapper - mapping datatable to class object using customtype converter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I'm new to AutoMapper and have couple of questions regarding datatable to object mapping.I did some work but seems like something went wrong.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, OrderDest>().ConvertUsing<OrderDestTypeConverter>();

public class OrderDestTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<IDataReader, OrderDest>
    {
        public OrderDest Convert(ResolutionContext context)
        {
            var dest = new OrderDest();
            if (!context.IsSourceValueNull && context.SourceValue is IDataReader)
            {
                var dr = (IDataReader) context.SourceValue;
                dest.OrderQuantityDest = (int) dr["quantity"];
            }
            return dest;
        }
    }
```

In my repository class - I'm doing this

```
  var crs = new CustomerRespositorySimulator();
  DataTable orderlistsource = crs.GetCustomerOrders(12345);
  var orderlistdest = Mapper.Map<IDataReader, List<OrderDest>>(orderlistsource.CreateDataReader());
```

For some reason the mapping does not work . I even attached a break in custom type converter **OrderDestTypeConverter** class and it never gets hit.

I'm doing any wrong in using customtype converter?.

Appreciate your help!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When converting from a `IDataReader` AutoMapper uses a special `IObjectMapper` internally which disregards any `ITypeConverter` you have applied to the mapping definition. Presumably this is so it has full control of iterating through the reader.

What you want to achieve can be done via the `ForMember` method when creating the map.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, OrderDest>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.OrderQuantityDest, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => (int)src["quantity"]));
```